# Mongo DB replica set configuration issue

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I know we need to have minimum 3 servers for mongo replica set  but I am trying to configure Mongo DB replica set with only two servers and If i want to add a aribter node. Please let me know where I can add the arbiter node and how to configure replica set with those (Primary-Secondary-Arbitary) configuration

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Start three instance of mongod, if you are using same server for all the instances make sure you change port and dbpath for each mongod.
If you are using different servers all the command can have port set as 27017.

```
mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27017 --bind_ip localhost,<hostname(s)|ip address(es)> --dbpath /srv/mongodb/rs0-0  --oplogSize 128
```

Step 2: After starting 3 instances using above you connect to mongo shell on any of the server and declare "cfg" variable.

```
cfg = {
  _id: "rs0",
  members: [
    {
     _id: 0,
     host: "<hostname1>:27017"
    },
    {
     _id: 1,
     host: "<hostname2>:27017"
    }
   ]
}
```

and run below command to configure replica set.
Note: if you are using same server for all your instances you change the port number of member _id: 1 to 27018.

```
rs.initiate( cfg )
```

Now you have successfully created a replica set with two instances.

Step 3: To add arbiter to replica set use below command:

```
rs.addArb("hostname3:27017")
```

Note: Same as step 2 if you using same server for all your instances change port in the above command to 27019.

Hope this helps.

Happy coding! Stay safe @ home :)